# Set a property value with different data types

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class, this class contains a public property which is a System.Drawing.Bitmap, but I want the consumer of my class to be able to set this value with a number of different types of image, without really having to think about what they are passing in, I will do the conversions neccessary behind the scenes. This is what I mean:

```
var myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(myBitmapImage);
var mySystemDrawingBitmap = new Bitmap(@"A:\b.c");

var classOne = new TestClass();
var classTwo = new TestClass();
var classThree = new TestClass();

//This should work:
classOne.MyImage = myBitmapImage;

//This should also work:
classTwo.MyImage = writeableBitmap;

//This should work too
classThree.MyImage = mySystemDrawingBitmap;
```

At the moment I am thinking of something like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Bitmap _myImage;

    public object MyImage
    {
        get
        {
            return _myImage;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value is Bitmap)
            {
                _myImage = (Bitmap)value;
            }

            if (value is BitmapImage)
            {
                var imageAsSystemDrawingBitmap = ConvertBitmapImageToBitmap((BitmapImage)value);
                _myImage = imageAsSystemDrawingBitmap;
            }

            if (value is WriteableBitmap)
            {
                var imageAsSystemDrawingBitmap = ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmap((WriteableBitmap)value);
                _myImage = imageAsSystemDrawingBitmap;
            }

            throw new Exception("Invalid image type");
        }
    }

    private Bitmap ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmap(WriteableBitmap value)
    {
        //do work here
        return null;
    }

    private Bitmap ConvertBitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage value)
    {
        //do work here
        return null;
    }
}
```

But using an object and casting feels very 2001, and I am sure there must be a more eloquent way to achieve this. Is there, or is this a bad idea in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `BitmapFactory` class that behaves as a factory to create a `Bitmap`, you can read more about the [Factory Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public BitmapFactory BitmapFactory { get; set; }
    public Bitmap Bitmap { get { return this.BitmapFactory.Bitmap; } }
}

public interface IBitmapFactory
{
    Bitmap Bitmap { get; }
}

public class BitmapFactory : IBitmapFactory
{
    public Bitmap Bitmap { get; private set; }

    public BitmapFactory(Bitmap value)
    {
        this.Bitmap = value;
    }

    public BitmapFactory(BitmapImage value)
    {
        this.Bitmap = ConvertBitmapImageToBitmap(value);
    }

    public BitmapFactory(WriteableBitmap value)
    {
        this.Bitmap = ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmap(value);
    }

    private Bitmap ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmap(WriteableBitmap value)
    {
        //do work here
        return null;
    }

    private Bitmap ConvertBitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage value)
    {
        //do work here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew that there was a name for it, but couldn't remember what it was or how it worked, thanks very much